Model definition in Keras tutorial "Probabilistic Bayesian Neural Networks" leads to error "AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'"
I am trying to run the keras-tutorial Probabilistic Bayesian Neural Networks to get an understanding of Bayesian neural networks (BNN). The tutorial contains a google-colab notebook, so you can run it directly within the browser. However, when I try to train the BNN for the first time (chapter Train BNN with a small training subset), it throws this error:
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-11-c94aabf54886> in <cell line: 5>()
      3 small_train_dataset = train_dataset.unbatch().take(train_sample_size).batch(batch_size)
      4 
----> 5 bnn_model_small = create_bnn_model(train_sample_size)
      6 run_experiment(bnn_model_small, mse_loss, small_train_dataset, test_dataset)

2 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_keras/src/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    249                 )
    250         if spec.min_ndim is not None:
--> 251             ndim = x.shape.rank
    252             if ndim is not None and ndim < spec.min_ndim:
    253                 raise ValueError(

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'

The error message probably refers to the model definition in the cell before:
Model Definition

def create_bnn_model(train_size):
    inputs = create_model_inputs()
    features = keras.layers.concatenate(list(inputs.values()))
    features = layers.BatchNormalization()(features)

    # Create hidden layers with weight uncertainty using the DenseVariational layer.
    for units in hidden_units:
        features = tfp.layers.DenseVariational(
            units=units,
            make_prior_fn=prior,
            make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            kl_weight=1 / train_size,
            activation="sigmoid",
        )(features)

    # The output is deterministic: a single point estimate.
    outputs = layers.Dense(units=1)(features)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

The code to start the training is this:
Start training
num_epochs = 500
train_sample_size = int(train_size * 0.3)
small_train_dataset = train_dataset.unbatch().take(train_sample_size).batch(batch_size)

bnn_model_small = create_bnn_model(train_sample_size)
run_experiment(bnn_model_small, mse_loss, small_train_dataset, test_dataset)

I tried wrapping the features - tensor into a tf.keras.input - layer, but it did not solve the problem

Hi, try checking your  the shape of the input tensors to the model, might be something tensorflow doesn't like

I added some print outs to check the type of the variables, but I cannot find the error. None of those is a tuple. The error seems to be caused by the line features = tfp.layers.DenseVariational ..., so I check all the parameters of that function call
Modified code:
def create_bnn_model(train_size):
    inputs = create_model_inputs()
    features = keras.layers.concatenate(list(inputs.values()))
    features = layers.BatchNormalization()(features)

    # Create hidden layers with weight uncertainty using the DenseVariational layer.
    print("start creating layers")
    for units in hidden_units:
        print("create layer")

        # print out the input parameters
        print("type units:" , type(units) )
        print("type prior", type(prior) )
        print("type posterior", type(posterior) )
        print("type kl_weight", type(1 / train_size) )
        print("type features: ",type(features) )

        features = tfp.layers.DenseVariational(  # This function call seems to cause the error
            units=units,
            make_prior_fn=prior,
            make_posterior_fn=posterior,
            kl_weight=1 / train_size,
            activation="sigmoid",
        )(features)
        print("layer created")

    # The output is deterministic: a single point estimate.
    outputs = layers.Dense(units=1)(features)
    model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=outputs)
    return model

Print out:
create model
start creating layers
create layer
type units: <class 'int'>
type prior <class 'function'>
type posterior <class 'function'>
type kl_weight <class 'float'>
type features:  <class 'keras.src.backend.common.keras_tensor.KerasTensor'>
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-31-7245de06a0fd> in <cell line: 7>()
      5 tf.debugging.disable_traceback_filtering() # to get the full error traceback
      6 print("create model")
----> 7 bnn_model_small = create_bnn_model(train_sample_size)
      8 print("run experiment" )
      9 run_experiment(bnn_model_small, mse_loss, small_train_dataset, test_dataset)

3 frames
/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/tf_keras/src/engine/input_spec.py in assert_input_compatibility(input_spec, inputs, layer_name)
    249                 )
    250         if spec.min_ndim is not None:
--> 251             ndim = x.shape.rank
    252             if ndim is not None and ndim < spec.min_ndim:
    253                 raise ValueError(

AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'rank'


